# How can I implement an edit link using yajra/laravel-datatables in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, datatable, laravel-5

I want to implement DataTables as a service, so I have followed this tutorial:
http://datatables.yajrabox.com/service

I have created a DataTable for my `User` collection using this command:

> php artisan datatables:make UsersDataTable

So, in my `app/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php` I have configured it as shown:

*I am trying to show records from two tables...*

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\User;
use Yajra\Datatables\Services\DataTable;

class UsersDataTable extends DataTable
{
    public function ajax()
    {
        return $this->datatables
            ->eloquent($this->query())
            ->addColumn('action', '<button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>')
            ->make(true);
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $users = User::query()
            ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
            ->select([
                'users.id',
                'users.name',
                'roles.name as role'
            ]);

        return $this->applyScopes($users);
    }

    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->ajax('')
                    ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                    ->parameters($this->getBuilderParameters());
    }

    private function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'name',
            'role'
        ];
    }

    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, this works as expected. This page runs on the following Url:

> http://my-domain.local/users

How can I link the `Edit` button to a link like this:

> http://my-domain.local/users/xxx/edit

Where `xxx` is the `id` of the row record?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it, this is how you do it:

```
public function ajax()
{
    return $this->datatables
        ->eloquent($this->query())
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/users/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/476

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add route path.., can do so as

```
 $actionBtn = '<a href="' . route("users", $row->id) . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>'; 

return $actionBtn;
```